# Kotlin: Higher Order Function : sortedWith()

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to learn kotlin from basic android kotlin codelabs [here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-collections?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-unit-3-pathway-1%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-training-collections#3), where a codelabs explains lambda and higher order functions. It shows an example of higher order function

> sortedWith()

we are using this method if we have to sort names list based on string length, as given in the codelab

```
fun main() {
    val peopleNames = listOf("Fred", "Ann", "Barbara", "Joe")
    println(peopleNames.sorted())
    println(peopleNames.sortedWith { str1: String, str2: String -> str1.length - str2.length })
}
```

The output of the above is given :

```
[Ann, Barbara, Fred, Joe]
[Ann, Joe, Fred, Barbara]
```

which is working fine, if i work on kotlin playground : [here](https://developer.android.com/training/kotlinplayground)
However, if I try to run this code on IntelliJ IDEA, I am getting an error :

```
Error:(37, 25) Kotlin: Type inference failed: fun <T> Iterable<T>.sortedWith(comparator: kotlin.Comparator<in T> /* = java.util.Comparator<in T> */): List<T>
cannot be applied to
receiver: List<String>  arguments: ((String, String) -> Int)
Error:(37, 35) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is (String, String) -> Int but kotlin.Comparator<in String> /* = java.util.Comparator<in String> */ was expected
```

Is there anything wrong with my kotlin version? My current kotlin version is :

> 1.3.50-release-112

Comment: update your kotlin version to 1.4.30

Comment: The linked Kotlin playground uses Kotlin 1.4.30, and you're apparently still using Kotlin 1.3. (side note: 1.3.50 is fairly old by now, especially considering the speed at which Kotlin receives updates/features. It's probably worth upgrading to 1.4.) Type inference has [changed a lot](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew14.html#new-more-powerful-type-inference-algorithm) since Kotlin 1.3 (though it is still optionally available in 1.3, I believe).

Answer (score 0):

Use compareBy

```
println( peopleNames.sortedWith(compareBy(
    { it.length },
    { it }
)))
```

output

```
[Ann, Barbara, Fred, Joe]
[Ann, Joe, Fred, Barbara]
```

Comment: It worked when I changed my kotlin language version and api version in IntelliJ IDEA to 1.4 from 1.3. Thanks btw.. :)